# How to make ActionMenu's menu appear with one mouseclick and disappear with a second?

Tags: gui-construction

How do I make ActionMenu's menu appear with one mouseclick of the button and disappear with a second consecutive click on the same button?  I would like to be able to click on an `ActionMenu` in order to inspect the action labels and then click on the `ActionMenu` button again to close the menu.  I believe this behavior is likely seen in many operating systems.  This functionality doesn't appear to be obviously supported within Mathematica's control objects, but I hope I'm wrong.

As my first attempt to get this working, I tried the following hoping that the `EventHandler` would re-evaluate the `ActionMenu` and set it to the initial view with the menu not visible but this "hacky" attempt didn't yield anything.  Here's the code:

```
EventHandler[ActionMenu["Print Factorials", {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], 
"10!" :> Print[10!]}], {"MouseClicked" :> ActionMenu[
"Print Factorials", {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], 
 "10!" :> Print[10!]}]}, PassEventsDown -> True]
```

I've also tried using `Mouseover` to achieve this idiomatic functionality without any luck.  Again, here's the code in case this helps:

```
Mouseover[ActionMenu[
Style["Print Factorials", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
FontSize -> 12], {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], 
"10!" :> Print[10!]}, Appearance -> None, Enabled -> False], 
ActionMenu[
Style["Print Factorials", FontFamily -> "Arial", 
FontSize -> 12], {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], 
"10!" :> Print[10!]}, Appearance -> None]]
```

Comment: The default behaviour of ActionMenu seems to be exactly as you want it to... if you click on any menu item or outside of the menu, it disappears.

Comment: @Gerli, create an ActionMenu and click the button to display the menu and then click the button again only to see that the menu remains displayed.  I never allowed for clicking outside of the button in my question but yes, I realize that this does cause the menu to disappear.  Now just try clicking the start menu in windows or a menu button on Linux and click once again on the same button to see the menu disappear.  I really don't see how this could be any more clearly asked in the subject.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but you may want to add why you don't use a [`PopupMenu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupMenu.html?q=PopupMenu) instead of an `ActionMenu`.

Comment: Using [`PopupView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupView.html) is another alternative.

Comment: @Karsten7. Only `ActionMenu` has `Method -> "Queued"`.

Comment: @Kuba Unlike `ActionMenu` `PopupMenu` and `PopupView` don't perform evaluations by themselves.

Comment: @Karsten7. They do, assignment to variable is an action, can be extended with 2nd argument of `Dynamic`, but that's not the point ;) You asked why not `PopupMenu`, can't be an alternative.

Comment: @Karsten 7.,  thanks for reopening.  The functionality of PopupMenu and PopupView satisfy my question regarding clicking to reveal and hide the menu, but my use-case constraint is to have an evaluation triggered by the selection of a menu item.  For example, I'd like to have a new notebook opened with some operations done.  This evaluation functionality didn't seem obvious to me in PopupMenu.

Comment: @rfrasier-mlp, on Linux, I can click on the button and it will disappear as well... but if I do a double click it will not disappear. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 4):

Since a `PopupMenu` exhibits a behavior you are after, let's adjust it to act like an `ActionMenu`:

```
myActionMenu[lbl_, actions_, opts___] := DynamicModule[{x = Unique[x]},
  PopupMenu[Dynamic[x, (# /. actions) &], First /@ actions, lbl, opts]
]


myActionMenu[
   "Print Factorials", 
   {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], "10!" :> Print[10!]}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

A modified version of [the solution provided by Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101303/18476), that behaves like an [`ActionMenu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ActionMenu.html) with the option setting `Method -> "Queued"`

```
popupActionMenu[lbl_, actions_] := 
 DynamicModule[{x, trigger}, 
  Row[{PopupMenu[Dynamic[Refresh[x, TrackedSymbols :> {}], (trigger =.; trigger = #) &], 
     First /@ actions, lbl, BaseStyle -> "ActionMenu", Appearance -> "ActionMenu"], 
    DynamicWrapper["", Refresh[trigger /. actions, TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}], 
     SynchronousUpdating -> False]}]]


popupActionMenu["Print Factorials", 
  {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> (Pause[6]; Print[7!]), "10!" :> Print[10!]}]
```

The `DynamicWrapper` could be replaced with

```
Dynamic[trigger /. actions; "", TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}, SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

---

A version based on [`PopupView`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PopupView.html)

```
popupActionMenu[lbl_, actions_] := DynamicModule[{n = 1},
  PopupView[actions[[All, 1]], Dynamic[n, (actions[[#, 2]]) &], ActionMenu[lbl, {}]]]


popupActionMenu["Print Factorials", 
  {"4!" :> Print[4!], "7!" :> Print[7!], "10!" :> Print[10!]}]
```

Comment: It seems that initial assignment fixes first action problem.